# Apache2 redirect all but some pages back to http using vhosts

Tags: https, apache2, url-rewriting

I am using rewrite rules with Apache 2 to redirect certain types of pages to HTTPS using vhosts.  These are anything that starts with `mydomain.com/users`. In other words, all pages having to do with users and their information should be on HTTPS. I want to redirect all other pages to HTTP.

What happens now is that when a user goes to a `/users` page, he is redirected fine to HTTPS. But when he navigates away from the `/users` area, I can't get the redirect back to HTTP.

I need the rules and conditions to rewrite anything that is NOT `/users/*` to HTTP. In other words, please help me fill in the blanks:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} __blank__
RewriteRule __blank__ http://mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

In researching this, there are a few things I am trying to avoid. I need a wildcard under `/users` because I am developing the app and often add pages under users (it's a Rails app).

I understand that it is not easy to do a NOT match with regular expressions. All I am trying to do here is have the bulk of the site run on HTTP except the `/users/*` pages on HTTPS.

Also, yes I have a valid cert and yes I have verified that the Apache2 rewrite mod works. I can get all URLs rewritten to HTTP no problem. How do I NOT rewrite ones that start with `/users` in the REQUEST_URI?  I think I have actually tried about every answer on this site so far...

Answer (score 3):

There quite a few answers for this sort of questions, -- you just need to search this site a bit. Yes, they do not answer your question 100% straight away (as everyone has slightly different requirements -- like different page name etc) but the whole approach is the same.

In any case -- here how it can be done:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# force https for /users/*
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^/users/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# force http for all other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# your other rewrite rules below
```

1. These rules need to be placed inside VirtualHost directive BEFORE any other rewrite rules (if such present). **If placed elsewhere** some small tweaking may be required.
2. They will

   - force HTTPS for all resources in `/users/`,
   - do nothing for images, css styles and JavaScript files (to be precise, for files with those extensions)
   - and will force HTTP for all other URLs

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** It is very likely that these rule will not work for you straight away. That is because modern browser do CACHE 301 redirects from your previous attempts. Therefore I recommend testing it on another browser and change 301 to 302 during testing (302 is not cached) .. or clear all browser caches (maybe even history) and restart browser.